# SUM with CASE counts duplicate rows in SQL GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I'm trying to do a `SUM` against all items which match a certain condition, like so:

```sql
SELECT l.Building_Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.Date >= '20180930' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Validated,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.id) Total
FROM Lab_Space s
JOIN Locations l ON s.Building_Code = l.Building_Code
GROUP BY l.Building_Name
```

The `COUNT` there is correct, and will say something like 20 because I can put the `DISTINCT s.id` in there.  However, my `SUM` ends up with something like 1500.  This is because when I do the `JOIN` rows are duplicated multiple times, and thus the `SUM` is counting against each one.

How can I do a SUM/CASE like this but make sure it only applies to distinct rows?

```sql
s.id    l.building_name  s.date
1       JF               2018-11-10
1       JF               2018-11-10
2       JF               2018-12-12
```

So if I have data like that, I'm going to get my count properly of 2, but validate will say 3 because the id of `1` appears twice due to doing a JOIN

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset. I'm trying to look into this. And temp data i created I can verify; that I'm also getting Validated = 3. What is your expected value??

Comment: you want the Validated value to count distinct s.id as well?

Comment: Got it; your answer is below. Let me know if that is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit this code of temp table if you deem fit.

```
   create table #temp_Lab_Space
    ([Date] date null
    ,Building_Code  int null

    )

    create table #temp_Locations 
    ( Building_Code  int null
    ,Building_Name varchar(10) null
    )


        insert into #temp_Lab_Space values
        ('2018-11-10',1)
        ,('2018-11-10', 1)
        ,('2018-12-12' , 1)

        insert into #temp_Locations values
        (1, 'JF')


select Building_Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date >= '20180930' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Validated,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Building_Code) Total
from (
select  distinct l.Building_Name, s.Building_Code, s.Date
,Rank_1 = rank() over(partition by l.Building_Name order by s.Date asc)
FROM #temp_Lab_Space s
JOIN #temp_Locations l ON s.Building_Code = l.Building_Code
) a
group by Building_Name
```

Comment: This clearly works with your sample data, but unfortunately it's not working with my full data.  I'll have to read up on the `ran() over` thing you did to try and figure out what's going on.

Comment: cool good sir. Glad your now pointed in the right direction ;)

Comment: if you can provide more sample data; I can perhaps edit my code to cover for it; in case our getting stuck. lmk.

Comment: So the `rank()` call was a red herring as it doesn't actually get used, but knowing to just run it through a sub-query (duh :)) was in fact the answer once I fixed the other issue with my code.

Comment: depending on the size of dataset in sub-query; you can insert that part into a temp table or variable (use any index as need be) AND then do a join back to your main queries. But if its running within a desired time I'm sure logic is much more readable as sub-query :D

Answer (score -1):

wild guess

```
select      l.Building_Name
            , count(s.Id)
            , sum(s.Validated)
from        Locations          l
cross apply (   select      s.Id
                            , max(case
                                      when s.Date >= '20180930' then 1
                                  else 0
                                  end) as Validated
                from        Lab_Space s
                where       s.Building_Code = l.Building_Code
                group by    s.Id) s
group by l.Building_Name
```

should give you the distinct space.id and a flag whether it is validated.

Comment: Nope, this still comes up with numbers that are way off.